# Route setup for same destination through different gateway and different interface

Tags: linux, networking

I have the following routes for eth5 in my Redhat.

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.8.0        10.185.2.14     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth5
10.0.10.0       10.185.2.14     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth5
```

I need to add 3 routes to eth4.

```
10.0.8.0/24 via 10.185.130.14 dev eth4
10.0.10.0/24 via 10.185.130.14 dev eth4
10.0.12.0/24 via 10.185.130.14 dev eth4
```

The following command prompted the error message.

```
$ ip route add 10.0.8.0/24 via 10.185.130.14 dev eth4
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

What is the correct approach to set up those routes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole point of the internet is it was built during the cold war. If something broke it tried an alternative. i.e Governments hate it not because there is no central control

Answer (score 0):

You already have a route to 10.0.8.0/24 and to 10.0.10.0/24. This causes error you're seeing.

So first, remove existing routes:

```
$ ip route del 10.0.8.0/24 via 10.185.2.14 dev eth5
$ ip route del 10.0.10.0/24 via 10.185.2.14 dev eth5
```

Comment: The original route for eth5 must be kept.

Comment: If you specify two routes for the same destination, i.e. `10.0.8.0/24`, one going out via `10.185.2.14` and second via `10.185.130.14`, how would you expect system to route outbound traffic?

Comment: I can send data to the same destination by binding to different interface. I can use "bind() command" in the program. Do I need to use  "ip rule" in this case?

Comment: Binding in program, if I understand you correctly, is meant to listen for new, incoming connections. You use `ip route` to set routes for outgoing traffic. What if, having two routes for the same destination, you issued `ssh 10.0.8.2`? How would kernel know whether to send packets via `10.185.130.14` or via `10.185.2.14`? That's why it's disallowed.

Comment: I know which source interface to use when I try to reach 10.0.8.2. So I bind to that source interface before connecting to that address.